# Android SQLiteException parameter

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working very well with the SQLite database, but now I have a problem while using a query.
For example, if use a query like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String parameter = mypar;
    String sql = SELECT color, name FROM table WHERE name = '" + parameter + "';
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
   while (c.moveToNext()) {
   String color = c.getString(0);
   String name = c.getString(1);
}
        c.close();
        db.close();
```

Everything works fine

But if the parameter has an apex

```
String parameter = mypar';
```

I get an exception

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "r": syntax error (code 1):
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: pos the exception and full code,

Comment: how are you executing the query? are you using .rawQuery? if so, you should use .query, and pass it as a parameter. It is also good to prevent sql injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my solution, works fine!! try it

```
String parameter = mypar';
String sql = SELECT color, name FROM table WHERE name = ?;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] { parameter });
```